# Ajax agregar varios usuarios a carta Api trello

Tags: javascript, ajax, trello

explico mi caso:
Yo estoy generando cartas en trello etiquetando a varios usuarios, cada usuario tiene su "código" por ejemplo (5891c93eb1cyl471ee1fe47c)
Yo tengo una función que añade 5 usuarios (esta función es llamada desde otra)
el caso es que estoy haciendo un POST a la api por cada usuario,  aunque me lo hace perfectamente creo que debe de hacerse de otra forma **¿alguna idea? ** lo  que uso:

```
 var datas = null;
var usuRQ1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
usuRQ1.open("POST", "https://api.trello.com/1/cards/" + data + "/idMembers?value=" + usuario1RRHH + "&key=" + appkeyRRHH + "&token=" + tokenRRHH);
usuRQ1.send(datas);

var usuRQ2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
usuRQ2.open("POST", "https://api.trello.com/1/cards/" + data + "/idMembers?value=" + usuario2RRHH + "&key=" + appkeyRRHH + "&token=" + tokenRRHH);
usuRQ2.send(datas);


var usuRQ3 = new XMLHttpRequest();
usuRQ3.open("POST", "https://api.trello.com/1/cards/" + data + "/idMembers?value=" + usuario3RRHH + "&key=" + appkeyRRHH + "&token=" + tokenRRHH);
usuRQ3.send(datas);


var usuRQ4 = new XMLHttpRequest();
usuRQ4.open("POST", "https://api.trello.com/1/cards/" + data + "/idMembers?value=" + usuario4RRHH + "&key=" + appkeyRRHH + "&token=" + tokenRRHH);
usuRQ4.send(datas);


var usuRQ5 = new XMLHttpRequest();
usuRQ5.open("POST", "https://api.trello.com/1/cards/" + data + "/idMembers?value=" + usuario5RRHH + "&key=" + appkeyRRHH + "&token=" + tokenRRHH);
usuRQ5.send(datas);
```

Answer (score 0):

Auto solucionado.
**Si tenéis alguna otra idea la agradezco**

```
var ArrUsuarios = [usuario1RRHH,usuario2RRHH,usuario3RRHH,usuario4RRHH,usuario5RRHH ]
var arrRQ = [];
var datas = null;
var usuRQ1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
for (let i = 0; i < ArrUsuarios.length; i++) {
    usuRQ1.open("POST", "https://api.trello.com/1/cards/" + data + "/idMembers?value=" + ArrUsuarios[i] + "&key=" + appkeyRRHH + "&token=" + tokenRRHH);
    usuRQ1.send(datas);
}
```